# Validation Of UserEmail Is not working in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am going to validate the POST variable `userEmail`. But the problem is even though I used `filter_var` to validate, it is not working even when inputting a wrong email and instead gets inserted. Can you help me in getting the solution.

**insert_dummy.php**

```
<html>
<head><title>Insertion</title>

</head>
<body>
<style>

#colour {
text-decoration:none;
}
</style>
<div id="display">
<?php
include('header/page_header.php');
include('db.php');



if(isset($_POST['add']))
{
$userName=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userName']);



$userEmail=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userEmail']);
if(!filter_var($userEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
echo "Please Enter The Valid Email Address";
}

$userPassword=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userPassword']);
$expiry_date1=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['expiry_date']);
$expiry_date=date("Y-m-d" ,strtotime($expiry_date1));
$end_date1=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['end_date']);
$end_date=date("Y-m-d",strtotime($end_date1));



 $regDate = date("Y-m-d");



function generateCode($characters) 
{
    $possible = '23456789abcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyz!@#$%^&*';
    $code = '';
    $i = 0;
    while ($i < $characters) { 
        $code .= substr($possible, mt_rand(0, strlen($possible)-1), 1);
        $i++;
    }
    return $code;
}

$registration_key=generateCode(10);



$str="insert into coeds_user(userName,userEmail,userPassword,regDate,expiry_date,registration_key) values('$userName','$userEmail','$userPassword','$regDate','$expiry_date','$registration_key')";


$query=mysql_query($str);
$userid=mysql_insert_id();
if($query)
{
$display="Success";
}

else
{
$display= "Failed";
}








$string="select * from coeds_user where userId=$userid";
$query2=mysql_query($string);
$display.="<table border='1' align='center'>";
$display.="<tr><th>UserName</th><th>UserEmail</th><th>UserPassword</th><th>RegDate</th><th>ExpiryDate</th><th>RegistrationKey</th><th colspan='3'>Action</th></tr>";
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($query2))
{
$display.="<tr>";

$display.="<td>".$result['userName']."</td>";
$display.="<td>".$result['userEmail']."</td>";
$display.="<td>".$result['userPassword']."</td>";
$display.="<td>".$result['regDate']."</td>";
$display.="<td>".$result['expiry_date']."</td>";
$display.="<td>".$result['registration_key']."</td>";
$display.="<td><a id='colour' class='tooltip' title='Edit' href='user_update.php?user_Id=".$result['userId']."'><img id='image' src='./images/small.gif'/></a></td>";
$display.="<td><a id='colour' class='tooltip' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Delete' href='user_delete.php?user_Id=".$result['userId']." '><img id='image' src='./images/trash.png'/></a></td>";

$display.="<td><a id='colour' class='tooltip' data-toggle='tooltip' title='insert' href='chapter_subscription_search.php?user_Id=".$result['userId']." '>i</a></td>";
$display.="</tr>";

$display.="</table>";

 $end_date1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+3 months"));
 $end_date2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+6 months"));
 $end_date3 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+9 months"));
 $page="";


 ?>

<table align='center' border='1'>

    <tr>

           <td> <label for="userId">UserId</label></td>
            <td ><input id="userId" name="userId"  type="text" value="<?php echo $userid;?>"/></td>


        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td> <label for="userName">UserName</label></td>
        <td ><input id="userName" name="userName" type="text" value="<?php echo $result['userName'];?>"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td> <label for="userEmail">UserEmail</label></td>
        <td ><input id="userEmail" name="userEmail" type="text" value="<?php echo $result['userEmail'];?>"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td> <label for="userPassword">UserPassword</label></td>
        <td ><input id="userPassword" name="userPassword" type="password" value="<?php echo $result['userPassword'];?>"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td> <label for="expiry_date">ExpiryDate</label></td>
        <td ><input id="expiry_date" name="expiry_date" type="text" value="<?php echo $result['expiry_date'];?>"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td> <label for="end_date">EndDate</label></td>
        <td >  <select name="end_date" id="end_date">
             <option value=<?php echo $end_date1; ?>><?php echo $end_date1; ?></option>
             <option value=<?php echo $end_date2; ?>><?php echo $end_date2; ?> </option>
             <option value=<?php echo $end_date3;?>><?php echo $end_date3;?> </option>

        </select>
</td>
        </tr>




        </table>

<?php
}
$str="select chapter_no from chapter_details ";


$query7=mysql_query($str);

$count=mysql_num_rows($query7);
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
{
$chap_lic=generateCode(50);
$chapter_no=mysql_result($query7,$i,'chapter_no');
$start_date=date('Y-m-d');
$expiry_date=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['end_date']);
$end_date1=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['end_date']);
$end_date=date("Y-m-d",strtotime($end_date1));
$s="insert into chapter_subscriptions (userId,chapter_no,start_date,end_date) values($userid,$chapter_no,'$start_date','$end_date')";

$query8=mysql_query($s);
}
$strings="select * from chapter_subscriptions where userId=$userid";
$query9=mysql_query($strings);
$display.="<table border='1' align='center'>";
$display.="<tr><th>ChapterNumber</th><th>StartDate</th><th>EndDate</th><th colspan='2'>Action</th></tr>";
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($query9))
{
$display.="<tr>";
$display.="<td>".$result['chapter_no']."</td>";
$display.="<td>".$result['start_date']."</td>";


$display.="<td>".$result['end_date']."</td>";


$display.="<td><a id='colour' class='tooltip' title='Edit' href='chapter_subscription_update.php?user_Id=".$result['userId']."'><img id='image' src='./images/small.gif'/></a></td>";
$display.="<td><a id='colour' class='tooltip' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Delete' href='chapter_subscription_delete.php?user_Id=".$result['userId']." '><img id='image' src='./images/trash.png'/></a></td>";

$display.="</tr>";
}
$display.="</table>";


echo $display;
}

?>
</div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#expiry_date" ).datepicker();
    $("#menuwrapper").hide();
    $("#unicode").click(function() {
        $("#menuwrapper").slideToggle(500);
    });
    });

</script>   


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **Don't** use the **deprecated and insecure** `mysql_*`-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you're actually not doing anything other then echoing a string if the email is invalid. The script still continues after that..

Comment: **Never store passwords in clear text!**. Only store password hashes! Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) . If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I _really_ hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) to get the same functionallity.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the fact that you are using deprecated code to interact with MySQL, the record is being inserted because although the email validation is working correctly, the rest of the code is still being executed.

If you insert a `die();` or redirect the user to an error page, the record will not be created.

```
$userEmail=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userEmail']);
if(!filter_var($userEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
echo "Please Enter The Valid Email Address";
exit();
// Or add a redirection here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using a flag variable `$valid`.

```
$valid = true;

if (!filter_var($userEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo "Please Enter The Valid Email Address";
    $valid = false; // Change to false when an error encounters
}


$userPassword=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userPassword']);
/* ------ Other code ---------- */
$registration_key=generateCode(10);

/* Execute INSERT query ONLY IF INPUTS ARE VALID i.e if $valid = true */

if ($valid) {

    $str="insert into coeds_user(userName,userEmail,userPassword,regDate,expiry_date,registration_key) values('$userName','$userEmail','$userPassword','$regDate','$expiry_date','$registration_key')";

    $query=mysql_query($str);
    $userid=mysql_insert_id();
    if($query) {
        $display="Success";
    } else {
        $display= "Failed";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please replace this

```
   if(!filter_var($userEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
      echo "Please Enter The Valid Email Address";
   }
```

with following

```
    $userEmail=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userEmail']);
    $email = (preg_match('/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/', $userEmail))?$userEmail:"invalid email";
    if($email == "invalid email")
    {
        echo "Please Enter The Valid Email Address";
        return; 
    }
```